# React-native add a widget to the android home screen

Tags: java, android, react-native, widget, android-widget

I have the following code:
https://github.com/lucas-kejan/React-Widget/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/androidwidgetpoc/BackgroundTaskBridge.java#L26

That should add the widget to the android home screen, when the method is called, but it does not work.

It gives me the following error:

```
lenght = 0; index = 0.
BackgroundTaskBridge.java:31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's take a look on things that you want to do - let user to pick widget and take a place in launcher. If you want to make it pre Oreo devices, where is no api for following action. So to run **PICK_APPWIDGET** intent you need appWidgetId. The only way to get appWidgetId by yourself is to bind id to appWidgetInfo, but this thing requires **BIND_APPWIDGET** permission, which is only available to system. So on pre Oreo device it's impossible to make a thing that you want (of course if you're not a system app).

On Oreo devices we have a new *pinning* widget api.

```
AppWidgetManager mAppWidgetManager =
context.getSystemService(AppWidgetManager.class);

AppWidgetProviderInfo myWidgetProviderInfo = new AppWidgetProviderInfo();
ComponentName myProvider = myWidgetProviderInfo.provider;

if (mAppWidgetManager.isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported()) {
  // Create the PendingIntent object only if your app needs to be notified
  // that the user allowed the widget to be pinned. Note that, if the pinning
  // operation fails, your app isn't notified.
  Intent pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent = new Intent( ... );

  // Configure the intent so that your app's broadcast receiver gets
  // the callback successfully. This callback receives the ID of the
  // newly-pinned widget (EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID).
  PendingIntent successCallback = PendingIntent.createBroadcast(context, 0,
          pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent);

  mAppWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, null,
           successCallback.getIntentSender());
}
```

Don't forget that it requires api version 26+. You can check documentation of following api [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html#widgets)

Comment: in the meantime, I thank you for having answered.
In fact, the version I'm using is a 7.0, would it be possible in the first versions of ore or to be able to add the widget to the home or not?
If I click on the add button, the menu appears to choose the widget, but in the end the widget is not inserted.
could you give me a hand?

Comment: on pre oreo devices the only way is to start PICK_APPWIDGET intent and let them find your widget and place by themselves widget on homescreen and your config activity will triggered for this action. Another option is detect onEnabled() where you can know appWidgetId and can update by intent service. it's a common case

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, you could show me how I can try these two cases.
I tried on stackoverflow, but I could not solve it.
If you are more comfortable, to show code, you can open an issue on the project.
I thank you in advance.

Comment: actually i just forgot about that it still will no work on pre Oreo device cuz you're not a Homescreen (to place the widget you need to pass appWidgetId that you can't handle as i write in answer), so it's still impossible for you. So i'm sorry that confuse you with my comment above. To sum up: it's impossible for api lower 26 to get case that you want...

Comment: So if I understood correctly, only with the version of oreo on, would it be possible to do it?
So I do not understand why I am given the possibility of being able to select the widget, even if it does not insert it, it seems a little strange to me.
For example for version 7.1, I found this article: http://www.frandroid.com/android/419766_android-o-les-applications-pourront-ajouter-des-widgets-sur-le-bureau

Comment: this api is given for launchers and system apps. Your link describes pinning widget  on Oreo device aswell.

Comment: I understand, so there is no solution for normal apps prior to Android 8.0, I'll give a reason.
Thank you. ;)
If by any chance you have time and do not distract yourself, you could take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364547/react-native-android-widget-listview